# Element deleting itself as soon as its made

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a basic game on my website that involves you trying to prevent jellyfish pictures from reaching the top of the page by clicking on them to make them disappear. When I try to spawn in a jellyfish into this game however it deletes itself right away. What puzzles me more is that the javascript console logs that the element was deleted before it logs that an event handler was added. Is the jellyfish element somehow calling the delete event as soon as I set that attribute? To spawn the jellyfish on the page I click an element but the jellyfish spawn nowhere near this element if this is helpful. The playingfield parent is in a separate html file.

```
/*Code with the problem*/
var deleteJelly = function(jelly) {
var parent = document.getElementById("playingField");
var child = jelly;
parent.removeChild(child);
console.log("Jellyfish removed!")};

var spawnJelly = function(jellyType) {
    jelliesSpawned++
    var newJelly = document.createElement("img");
    newJelly.setAttribute('src', "https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B-IaOP2CvHbffk56ZWFrUExfX1ZVNWZ0RmRmYU0tMHVoUHVDZzJ1NzhRV2l0c01kSENnNWc/jelly"+jellyType+".png");
    document.getElementById("playingField").appendChild(newJelly);
     newJelly.addEventListener("click", deleteJelly(newJelly));
    console.log("added event listener")
};
/*Rest of code works fine*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass *jelly* as the element calling the listener is *this* within the function. You can leverage that to simplify it to:

```
function deleteJelly() {
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  console.log("Jellyfish removed!")
}
```

and setting the listener:

```
newJelly.addEventListener("click", deleteJelly);
```

which is a lot less code all round. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You've fallen for the classic "calling the function instead of passing the function" error.

```
 newJelly.addEventListener("click", deleteJelly(newJelly)); // call function
```

vs

```
 newJelly.addEventListener("click", function(){deleteJelly(newJelly);}); // pass function
```

It is deleted immediately because you have called the function, so it did what it is supposed to do: delete.

If instead you pass in an anonymous function that calls delete, then delete will not be called until the anonymous function is called - which is when you want it to happen.